# Best CSS buttons that are cross browser, degrade gracefully, and work on input or link

Tags: css

I have seen a lot of good attempts at CSS buttons  (for example http://ubuwaits.github.com/css3-buttons/ )

But I haven't seen one emerge yet that is safe to use in production and meets all the following requirements:

- Looks good on all modern browsers
- Degrades gracefully on older browsers down to at least IE7 (bonus if IE6) - don't care if they look as good, as long as they aren't noticeably bad
- Works equally well on an input tag (submit button) or link (a tag)

What are the best ones people are using in production?

Comment: I'm interested to see the answers to this question too.

Answer (score 1):

Better still use css sprites. This involves putting all the button states in one image file and setting this as a background-image property. By changing the position of the background-image at different states (active, hover) the image appears to switch when in fact all it does is change position. Google css sprites tutorial for more.

Also your navigation bar or list should be an unordered list with each button as a

element. This degrades best.

Comment: I've done this on a number of projects but have found it to be a big source of bugs and it slows down development.  CSS sprites are still difficult for a few reasons.  Special attention it required to get regular button functionality like disabling after a submit, or the enter key submitting the form.  Not to mention they are harder to maintain for changing button text etc and lengthen development time.  Part of my reason for posting this was to get around the necessity of using image sprites.  Should have made that more clear...as CSS gets better I think this sprites will become less popular.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery UI - you dont have to use they javascript to make them buttons - you can just use the classes and have them all nice and glitzy! :)

See [button examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#icons)

they degrade really well and they use  which means you can have nice html content in them aswell ;). Also means you can have fully themeable buttons using themeroller

see: [themeroller link](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)